# Powershell - Connect-ExchangeOnline

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm trying to connect to 365 Powershell using PS 7 but i'm getting the following error

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RestApiClient.ExchangeEnvironment].
```

my version is the below

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.2.5
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.5
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19043
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Is it because i'm using the Core Edition maybe?

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out, was me being silly

Comment: For the sake of others having this same issue, could you explain what caused the problem and what the fix was?

Comment: As Theo said, please update this answer with details if this issue was something you think other people would be likely run into. However, if it was just a typo or something that won't be helpful to anyone, this question/answer pair should be deleted.

Comment: Well i thought i had figured it out but now i realise you got to put Import-Module MSOnline -UseWindowsPowershell as Powershell 7.0 isnt compatible anymore, it sounds like they are moving to this Graph SDK but i need to look into this more.

Comment: Might be best to simply delete this question and answer.